# Unable to test game in game maker studio 1.4

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-1.4

My son is trying to create his first game using Game Maker Studio 1.4. We followed all steps in the book we are using (Game maker for kids). We now want to try to run the game, but it does not work.

Game Maker shows a Windows dialog that says "Open.." in the title and where you can select "Exe files (*.exe, *.ios, *.psp, *.win, *.droid)". I have no clue what file I should select here? If I cancel, I get a dialog that says "Compile failed, please check the compile window". But there is no error in the compile window, just a message "Compilation finished"

Comment: Did you manage to make it work ? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Do let me know if you find something.

Comment: If I find something I will post it as an answer for sure ! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to make the game run on Windows OS, so these steps should work for you.
(Clicking the blue numbers will dispaly and image relevant to the step)

**1**. Firstly make sure the platform target is for Windows and not a different platform as shown here:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt6lB.png) You click on the drop-down arrow to change the platform you wish to run/export your game too.

**2**. Now that we have that out of the way near the top left of the screen there should be a green play button. I have circled the button on this image to help you.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1fZO.png) You need to click this Green Play button.

**3**. After that Game Maker Studio will compile the code (this may take some time depending on how fast your PC is and how big the game is). You can tell if it is compiling if there is a loading box in the centre of the screen. Also remember to be *patient* as it could take a while.

**4**. If you have no errors in your code the game will successfully launch and you will be able to play it. If it didn't launch then Game Maker Studio will point out where errors in the code are to make fixing them easier.

I hope this guide helps and if you need any more help then just ask on the forms and I'm sure someone will be able to help you. Have a nice day and happy game developing!

Comment: Does not help. Target was set to Windows. I still get the dialog asking me to choose an Exe file.

Comment: Ok, could you possibly post a screenshot of this dialog?

Answer (score 0):

On the GM:S settings (File -> Preferences) on the window view, press "check Windows sdk".

If it turns red => reinstall Windows sdk and Windows visual studio 11 then specify path.

Let me know if it solved your PB

Answer (score 0):

In the `Files -> Preferences` there's a `Temp directory` box and mine was set to a dummy drive.

I set it to the actual `Temp directory` of my computer and now it works well.

[image]